# Cant understand why my onclick does not work

Tags: javascript

I am currently studying Javascript and came across a problem while practising `setInterval()` and `clearInterval().

I am writing a timer that will stop as soon as I press on a button. I have a variable in which I start the interval, a function that executes the timer code and writes the current number the timer is on into a div in HTML.

Then I have a `getElementById` call that writes an `onclick` into a button with an id of `theButton` which contains a `clearInterval`.

The problem is, if I just write the `clearInterval` right in the end of the code, without an `onclick`, it works. But as soon as I write it inside an `onclick`, it doesn't work without even showing a error.

I have tried searching on the internet and the only answer I got was to use a `var` instead of a `let` for the variable with the interval, but that didn't work.

```js
var timerVariable = setInterval(theTimer, 1000);
let count = 11;

function theTimer() {
  if (count != 0) {
    count--;
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += count;
    console.log("its working");
  }
}
document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = 'clearInterval(timerVariable)';
```

Comment: A string is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason it doesn't work is because you should assign a *function reference* to `onclick`, not a string. Your code should look something like this:

```
document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
  clearInterval(timerVariable);
});
```

However, taking this a step further, the `onclick` is no longer considered good practice. A better solution is to attach your events using `addEventListener()`, like this:

```
document.querySelector('#theButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timerVariable);
});
```

Here's a full working version with the above correction applied. Note that I added an `else` case to also clear the interval when the count reaches `0`. Without this the interval will run infinitely without any purpose.

```js
var timerVariable = setInterval(theTimer, 1000);
let count = 11;

function theTimer() {
  if (count != 0) {
    count--;
    document.querySelector("div").innerHTML += count;
    console.log("its working");
  } else {
    clearInterval(timerVariable);
  }
}

document.querySelector("#theButton").addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(timerVariable);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="theButton">Stop</button>
<div></div>
```